# How can I retrive data from mysql database to flutter application?

Tags: android, mysql, flutter, phpmyadmin

I created a MySQL database in PHPMyAdmin using the free hosting of 000webhost. I want to get the data in my flutter application in a Listview. I'm just wondering if I can do that without using any API. Does flutter allow getting data from an internet server without using API?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is not possible, since you need some sort of logic to handle what you want to take from database, and what you want to add into it, or other parts of CRUD. And that will be your API. I would recommend to take a look at some REST API tutorials, where you can build simple interface to send data to your flutter app or other applications. Try [this](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/03/08/simple-rest-api-php) for example.